# How to retrieve already cached data inside webapi controller method C#

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, outputcache

I have created a `OutputCacheFilter` attribute by inheriting `ActionFilterAttribute` to get the caching functionality for the controller method.

This is my `OutputCacheFilter` class

```
public class OutputCacheFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        // cache length in seconds
        private int _timespan;
        // true to enable cache
        private bool _cacheEnabled = false;
        // true if the cache depends on the caller user
        private readonly bool _dependsOnIdentity;
        // cache repository
        private static readonly ObjectCache WebApiCache = MemoryCache.Default;
        //private readonly SecurityHelper _securityHelper;
        private readonly bool _invalidateCache;

    public OutputCacheFilter()
        : this(true)
    {
    }

    public OutputCacheFilter(bool dependsOnIdentity)
        : this(dependsOnIdentity, false)
    {
    }

    public OutputCacheFilter(bool dependsOnIdentity, bool invalidateCache)
    {
        //_securityHelper = new SecurityHelper();
        _dependsOnIdentity = dependsOnIdentity;
        _invalidateCache = invalidateCache;

        ReadConfig();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (_cacheEnabled)
        {
            if (filterContext != null)
            {
                if (IsCacheable(filterContext))
                {
                    string _cachekey = string.Join(":", new string[]
                    {
                        filterContext.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString,
                        filterContext.Request.Headers.Accept.FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                    });

                    //if (_dependsOnIdentity)
                    //    _cachekey = _cachekey.Insert(0, _securityHelper.GetUser());

                    if (WebApiCache.Contains(_cachekey))
                    {
                        //TraceManager.TraceInfo(String.Format
                        //("Cache contains key: {0}", _cachekey));

                        var val = (string)WebApiCache.Get(_cachekey);
                        if (val != null)
                        {
                            filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse();
                            filterContext.Response.Content = new StringContent(val);
                            var contenttype = (MediaTypeHeaderValue)WebApiCache.Get(_cachekey + ":response-ct");
                            if (contenttype == null)
                                contenttype = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(_cachekey.Split(':')[1]);
                            filterContext.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = contenttype;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_cacheEnabled)
            {
                if (WebApiCache != null)
                {
                    string _cachekey = string.Join(":", new string[]
                    {
                        filterContext.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString,
                        filterContext.Request.Headers.Accept.FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                    });

                    //if (_dependsOnIdentity)
                    //    _cachekey = _cachekey.Insert(0, _securityHelper.GetUser());

                    if (filterContext.Response != null && filterContext.Response.Content != null)
                    {
                        string body = filterContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                        if (WebApiCache.Contains(_cachekey))
                        {
                            WebApiCache.Set(_cachekey, body, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_timespan));
                            WebApiCache.Set(_cachekey + ":response-ct",
                            filterContext.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_timespan));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WebApiCache.Add(_cachekey, body, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_timespan));
                            WebApiCache.Add(_cachekey + ":response-ct",
                            filterContext.Response.Content.Headers.ContentType, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(_timespan));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (_invalidateCache)
            {
                CleanCache();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TraceManager.TraceError(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void CleanCache()
    {
        if (WebApiCache != null)
        {
            List<string> keyList = WebApiCache.Select(w => w.Key).ToList();
            foreach (string key in keyList)
            {
                WebApiCache.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReadConfig()
    {
        if (!Boolean.TryParse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheEnabled"], out _cacheEnabled))
            _cacheEnabled = false;

        if (!Int32.TryParse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CacheTimespan"], out _timespan))
            _timespan = 1800;
    }

    private bool IsCacheable(HttpActionContext ac)
    {
        if (_timespan > 0)
        {
            if (ac.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong Arguments");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**This is My controller**

```
public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    [OutputCacheFilter()]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMessages()
    {
        MesssageManager msgManager = null;
        try
        {
            msgManager = new MesssageManager();
            List<Message> messages = msgManager.GetMessages();
            return Ok(messages);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            msgManager = null;
        }
    }


    public IHttpActionResult GetMessage(string messageCode)
    {
        Message msg = null;
        MesssageManager msgManager = null;
        try
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageCode))
            {
                throw new Exception("Plase pass the messageCode in order to get the message.");
            }
            msgManager = new MesssageManager();
            List<Message> messages = msgManager.GetMessages();
            msg = messages.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Code.Equals(messageCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            return Ok(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            msgManager = null;
        }
    }

}
```

**DTO Model**

```
public class Message
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public char IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In my collroller there are two methods

1. GetMessages - This method retrieves the all messaged from database and store in `cache` so it is decorated by `OutputCacheFilter` attribute to accomplish it.
2. GetMessage - This method is used to get the single message by messageCode, this is currently calling the database method to get the all code and then in result it search the message by messageCode.
   Here I want to retrieve the message from `cache` it self by calling the same controller method "GetMessages()" so if cache is available then get from cache result else from database as GetMessages() is doing.

To do so I called the `GetMessages()` controller method in my `GetMessage()` but is always retrieve the message from database, it does not consider cached message.

Please help me to implement the correct approach for this scenario.

Comment: That's not how output caching works or is intended to. Output caching ensures that the first HTTP request to a specific output-cached resource is cached by the server, and that subsequent HTTP requests **for that same resource** are returned from the server's cache, so that the server code for that resource isn't called more than once. In other words: assuming your OutputCacheFilterAttribute works correctly, your controller code doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: thanks @lanKemp, I got the point , but if I still want to get the cached data inside my controller method so there in no other way/approach? to avoid database calling when data is cached.

Comment: Perhaps you confuse output caching with in-memory caching of data? Or did you realize that the `OutputCache` attribute in ASP.NET Web API doesn't work? You need to add an extra package like [this one covered by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekASPNETWebAPICachingWithCacheCowAndCacheOutput.aspx) to enable output caching.

Comment: To cache data between requests you can use the classes in the [System.Runtime.Caching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. Check the documentation of the [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.

Comment: Thanks  @PanagiotisKanavos, My requirement is faster retrieval of frequently used data so I want to cache it, In my web API I have used 'MemoryCache' that is probably a in-memory caching. I wrongly named the filter attribute class.   Panagiotis is there any other way to do the caching in web API or my approach is correct ?, I am designing the web api first time hence I am not much aware of it.