# Deserializing JSON string to actual object for conditional data only using Newtonsoft c#

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, json-deserialization

I am working in web API project where I have stored the list of data (`List<someClass>`) in `cache` as `JSON` string, This cache object may have thousands of records, some time we need to get few record from that cached list but as the data stored in cache as a JSON string we have to  'Deserialize' it first then in converted object (`List<someClass>`) we search the item by using `Linq`. 
This process unnecessarily converting the whole JSON string to object to get the few items only that I want to tune, if there is any way to `Deserialize` only condition value in JSON string.

currently I am using  `Newtonsoft.Json` library for DeSerilization.

```
    public static T ConvertToType<T>(string jsonResponse)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonResponse) ? result : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
        return result;
    }
```

This is a Sample JSON string That I have store in `cache`

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Code": "SAVE_SUCCESS",
        "Description": "Record successfully saved.",
        "Type": "0",
        "IsActive": "Y"
    },

    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Code": "SAVE_SUCCESS_PARAM",
        "Description": "{0} successfully saved.",
        "Type": "0",
        "IsActive": "Y"
    },

    {
        "ID": 8,
        "Code": "DUPLICATE_CHECK",
        "Description": "This {0} already exists.",
        "Type": "2",
        "IsActive": "Y"
    },

    {
       "ID": 12,
       "Code": "RESTORE_SUCCESS",
       "Description": "Record successfully restored.",
       "Type": "0",
       "IsActive": "Y"
    },

]
```

Suppose in above JSON string and I want to get only that element which have `"Code": "DUPLICATE_CHECK"` then the serilization should happen only for following part only and as a result I should get only one record in List or as a indivisual item whatever possible.

```
{
    "ID": 8,
    "Code": "DUPLICATE_CHECK",
    "Description": "This {0} already exists.",
    "Type": "2",
    "IsActive": "Y"
}
```

Please suggest me if there is any way to do this.

Comment: Why cache data as string and not as already hydrated objects? No need to serialize, just cache the object collection as is. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi  the data storing in cache by controller method using ActionFilterAttribute can you please check my this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288351/how-to-retrieve-already-cached-data-inside-webapi-controller-method-c-sharp , I am reading the data inside OnActionExecuted method from filterContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result hence it stored in cache as a JSON string.